# how to get data from a span inside a div with javasript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a div with a class and inside it I have a button and a span.

How do I get the data from the span only using JavaScript?

```
<div _ngcontent-c26 class="ad" fieldname="xzc" panelname="zx">
      
      <span _ngcontent-c26>12345678</span>
      
      <button>hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: <div _ngcontent-c26 class="asd" fieldname="qwe" panelname="ert">
<span _ngcontent-c26>12345678<span>
<button>hello<button>
<div>
//ignore the mistakes

Comment: You need to write Javascript code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I did try JS
but what I used gave me the whole DIV (the data and the elements) and I didn't need it
so I thought to leave it blank so people won't be fixed on my attempt...
I tried - document.getElementsByClassName("ad")[0].innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` to target elements in the DOM with a CSS style syntax - perhaps like:

```
let div=document.querySelector('div.ad[fieldname="xzc"][panelname="zx"]')
```

Comment: Why do you think this low-effort question does deserve an answer instead of a close vote?

Comment: what else did u want me to add?
I wrote the problem with the HTML code
what else can I write?

Comment: I used something similar to your answer 
like this - document.querySelectorAll('.ad')[0].querySelector('span').innerHTML
and it worked it gave the number alone
thank u for the help